# Adding days to a specific date inside an array

Tags: php

I have a TABLE `events`

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data` date DEFAULT NULL,
`days` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

with a number of records.

I generate an array with all unavailable dates

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE `data` LIKE '".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-%'";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
$unavailable[] = $row["data"];
$days[] = $row["days"];
}
```

The array $unavailable is like this: (2012-08-10, 2012-08-25)
The array $days is like this: (3, 2)

I need an array like this: (2012-08-10, 2012-08-11, 2012-08-12, 2012-08-25, 2012-08-26)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that generates what you want.

```
<?php

$unavailable = array('2012-08-10', '2012-08-25');
$days = array(3, 2);

$dates = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($days); $i++)
{
    $tm = strtotime($unavailable[$i]);
    for ($d = 0; $d < $days[$i]; $d++)
    {
        $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $tm + $d * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
}
print_r($dates);
?>
```

You could move this code into to while loop of your code to prevent creating the $unavailable and $days arrays

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"  I have 8 :(